# How to compare estimates between glm models?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, interpretation

I have a dataset with counts of four different markers per gene and samples from two origins. I have performed a glm to see if the `origin` of the sample is significant in predicting these counts an it is:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: count ~ variable + gene
Model 2: count ~ origin + variable + gene
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)   
1       459     349.44                        
2       458     342.11  1    7.328 0.006789 **
```

I next wanted to see what of the four markers (seen above in the model as `variable`) is the primary driving force for the difference between counts in `origin`.

To do this I performed a glm on the dataset subset by `origin` and then looked at the coefficients to see if there is any difference in the coefficient significance.

## On origin 1:

```
Call:
glm(formula = count ~ variable, family = "poisson", data = count_filt_FGT_free[count_filt_FGT_free$origin == 
    "free", ])
Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.4975  -1.3926  -0.6276   0.0306   4.0598  

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)          -0.03077    0.12500  -0.246    0.806    
variableDuplication   0.14518    0.17070   0.851    0.395    
variableKnown_target -1.59393    0.30421  -5.240 1.61e-07 ***
variablePhylogeny     0.13158    0.17124   0.768    0.442    
---
```

## On origin 2:

```
Call:
glm(formula = count ~ variable, family = "poisson", data = count_filt_FGT_free[count_filt_FGT_free$origin == 
    "FGT", ])

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6877  -0.6963  -0.3758  -0.2252   5.1953  

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)            0.2171     0.1104   1.966   0.0493 *  
variableDuplication    0.1366     0.1511   0.904   0.3661    
variableKnown_target  -1.6341     0.2733  -5.980 2.23e-09 ***
variablePhylogeny      0.1259     0.1515   0.831   0.4060    
---
```

So here I see that `variableKnown_target` is significant in both models, but `the intercept is only significant in model two.

Given my understanding that as this is a count based glm the intercept is just the fourth `variable` would that mean this fourth `variable` is a driving force for why we saw `origin`to have significance?

Comment: You seem to be very concerned with "significance". You are correct that the intercept is the value of the outcome when `variable` is at its reference level. I would say that in the first model there is almost no evidence that the reference level for `variable` is associated with a count greater than zero, whereas i the second model there is some evidence

Comment: @RobertLong Does this then mean that `variable` at its reference level has evidence for it being the driving force in difference between the count distributions of the two datasets?

Comment: I would not like to say that. I would fit a model on the whole dataset. Splitting the data is very rarely a useful excercise.

Comment: Say the example of "On origin 2" is the model fitted to the whole dataset, how would you interpet driving force if that were the output?